Solve $\Bigl(2 \sin(x)D^2+2 (\cos(x)+\sin(x))D\Bigr)y+2y\cos(x)=\cos(x)$
How to solve the following differential equation?
$$2 \sin(x)\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+2 \cos(x) \frac{dy}{dx}+2 \sin(x) \frac{dy}{dx}+2y \cos(x)=\cos(x)$$
This was given to me by one of my friends as a friendly challenge, but it appears that he himself doesn't know the solution. What we tried was various sorts of trigonometric solutions but that didn't work out. I think power series methods would be overkill. Even symbolic languages including Mathematica and mathdf can't find the solution to this problem. I also tried putting various ansatz based on a numerical solution but they all seem to result in inconsistencies, but this might be a very easy problem. How to approach this? Also, tips for attacking some problems are welcome. Apologies for my silliness, because I am new to math and just entered high school. Thanks a lot in advance.

Please at least simplify to $$\left(D^2+(\cot x+1)D+\cot x\right)y=\frac12\cot x$$ and start from here.

I guess you can immediately spot the solution, right?

@MathArt but what about the homogeneous solution?

Sorry, in the beginning I make a wrong judge about the integral of $\cot x$ in exponential form. The integral factor $e^{\int(1+\cot x)dx}=e^x\sin x$ might still be useful.

The differential equation can be rewritten as
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin x\frac{dy}{dx} \right) + \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin x \:y\right) = \frac{1}{2}\cos x$$
Integrating both sides, we obtain
$$\sin x \left(\frac{dy}{dx}+y\right) = \frac{1}{2}\sin x + C_1 \implies y'+y = \frac{1}{2} + C_1\csc x$$
then multiplying both sides by $e^x$ and integrating again, we get
$$e^xy'+e^xy = \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^xy\right) = \frac{1}{2}e^x + C_1e^x\csc x$$
$$\implies \boxed{y = \frac{1}{2}+C_2e^{-x}+C_1\int_1^x e^{t-x}\csc t \:dt}$$

Please allow me here as a trial to find the solution but probably in a slightly different way. The notation $D$ throughout is the differential operator w.r.t. $x$.
Equivalently, the original equation can be written as:
$$
\Bigl(D^2+(\cot x+1)D+\cot x\Bigr)y=\frac12\cot x
$$
which can be split to two 1st order ODEs as (note the order matters)
\begin{align}
(D+\cot x)v&=\frac12\cot x\tag1\\
(D+1)y&=v\tag2
\end{align}
One can easily find the solution to $\textbf{(1)}$
\begin{align}
v&=\frac12\frac{1}{D+\cot x}\cot x\\
 &=e^{-\int\cot{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\left[\int\left(e^{\int\cot{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\frac12\cot{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x+c_1\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin{x}}\left[\frac12\int\left(\sin{x}\cot{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x+c_1\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin{x}}\left[\frac12\sin{x}+c_1\right]\\
&=\frac12+c_1\csc{x}.
\end{align}
So the next is to solve $\textbf{(2)}$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
(D+1)y&=\frac12+c_1\csc{x}
\end{align}
which is solved similarly by
\begin{align}
y&=\frac{1}{D+1}\left(\frac12+c_1\csc{x}\right)\\
&=e^{-x}\left[\int\left(e^x(\frac12+c_1\csc{x})\right)\,\mathrm{d}x+c_2\right]\\
&=\frac12+c_1e^{-x}\int e^x\csc{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+c_2e^{-x}.
\end{align}
Note the last integral is not convergent, but it might be evaluated in series by
$$
y=\frac12+c_1\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kD^k(\csc{x})
$$
Appreciate your kind corrections if errors are found.
